# How to filter the data and plot a column chart using the facet wrap in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, column-chart

https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/netflix-shows-and-movies-exploratory-analysis/notebook contains the data set. (File size is 2.1 MB)

I am looking the achieve the following things the data set - 
Identify the top 25 leading actors from the countries of United States, United Kingdom and India.

The code that I worked out is as follows,

```
library(tidyverse)
net_flix <- read.csv("netflix_titles_nov_2019.csv")

net_flix %>% 
    separate_rows(country, sep = ",")%>% 
    filter(country == "India"| country == "United States"| country == "United Kingdom")%>%
    separate_rows(cast, sep = ",")%>%
    count(cast)%>%
    slice_max(n, n = 25)%>%
    ggplot(aes(y = fct_reorder(cast, n), x = n))+
    geom_col()
```

The resultant output is as follows,

[image]

The expected output is as follows,(only the top part of the chart)

[image]

The attempt is made after reviewing the suggested question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55864054/filtering-the-data-using-pickerinput-and-plotting-based-on-the-filtered-data-i`

Comment: looks like you need a `facet_wrap()` command

Comment: @Ben when I include facet_wrap(country~.) in the above code, I am getting the following  error:( At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `country`.* Plot is missing `country`
* Layer 1 is missing `country`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The issue with `facet_wrap` is that in order to facet by country you have to count by both cast and country. Also. To get the bars ordered in each facet I make use of tidytext::reorder_within and tidytext::scale_x_reordered:

```
library(tidyverse)
net_flix <- read.csv("netflix_titles_nov_2019.csv")

net_flix %>% 
  separate_rows(country, sep = ",")%>% 
  filter(country == "India"| country == "United States"| country == "United Kingdom")%>%
  separate_rows(cast, sep = ",")%>%
  # Count by country and cast
  count(country, cast)%>%
  slice_max(n, n = 25)%>%
  ggplot(aes(y = tidytext::reorder_within(cast, n, country), x = n))+
  geom_col() +
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~country, scales = "free")
```

This gives me this plot:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to arrive the plot that resembles the expected output ?